# How access an uiview subview partially outside of his parent uiview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

I have the following UIVIew architecture (x,y,width,height) :

```
- MainWindow (0,0,768,1024)
    - MainView (0,0,768,80) 
        - containerview (500,40,120,80)
            - subview (500,40,120,80) 
                -some buttons
```

My problem is that the bottom of the subview lay outside of the bound of MainView.  Buttons at the **bottom** of subview are not responsive.  The one at the top are responsive, because their position is also inside on Mainview.

So when i try to click the buttons at the bottom of subview i actually click on MainWindow!  Position of bottoms buttons of subview are not inside of MainView

Is there a way to make all my subview available even if half of it is outside of MainView bound?

I know that i can create the subview directly under MainWindow instead, but i don't want to redo my code.

**Update**
Here how is design my views :
A = MainWindow, B = MainView, C = container view, D = subview, X = where i want to click

```
+----------------------------+
|A                           |
|+-------------------------+ |
||B                        | |
||            +----------+ | |
|+------------|C&D       |-+ |
|             |X         |   |
|             +----------+   |
+----------------------------+
```

THank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [interaction beyond bounds of uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)

Answer (score 13):

You need to implement `hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in your MainView.

[See the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

> Points that lie outside the receiver’s bounds are never reported as
>   hits, even if they actually lie within one of the receiver’s subviews.
>   Subviews may extend visually beyond the bounds of their parent if the
>   parent view’s clipsToBounds property is set to NO. However, hit
>   testing always ignores points outside of the parent view’s bounds.

Addressing a comment:

You should subclass UIView. Then set the class of MainView in the nib to your UIView subclass.

[Some hittesting is discussed here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html), but I wasn't able to find clear explanation of how it works.

[Try this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-re)

I haven't tested it, but the following code might do what you need:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for(UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        UIView *view = [subview hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:subview] withEvent:event];
        if(view) return view;
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply.  I took a quick look over the net to see how to use hitTest. Didn't find that much.  I am not sure to what to do.  Actually, MainView is a xib.  Do i need to create my own class MainView subclassing UIView and re-implement hitTest?

Another question, does hittest will be call even when i will click outside MainView?

Comment: Ok, i've found the link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-re)  From what i understand, if i implement hittest in MainView, this method won't be called when i will click at the bottom of subview...

Comment: This is an old thread, but if anybody's looking for the solution... I have a QuadCurveMenu (from github) as a UINavigationBar's rightButtonItem. Only the button on top of the nav bar was working. Subclassed UINavigationBar, used this implementation, and everything works! Thanks Jiri!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but if the subview is visible but not within the MainView then the only way to get actions from subview to MainView is to receive them in the subview and pass them onto MainView.

If that isn't an answer I need more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you check the coordinate of subview (500,40) the top of this view is over Mainview and the bottom part is over MainWindow.  My problem is when i click a button from the bottom part of subview.  From my understanding, because subview belongs to MainView, i cannot access part after y axis 80 (the height of MainView).  Actually, when a click to the bottom part of subview, i do click on MainWindow.  Do not if it is better :/

Comment: Yes, in fact if you set the parent view to clip subviews you wouldn't even see that portion of the subview. But what is it exactly that you  are trying to accomplish? What Jiri has posted could work in your case, but then you have to manually execute the actions which is a PITA and removes the benefits of using Interface builder.

Probably an easier way to accomplish what it is you are after.

Comment: What i want to do is the following : MainView has a save button.  When the user clicks on the save button, it actually opens subview (as post-it style, with transition animation) and the subview has more information about the save.  When you click on the buttons from subview, it delegates processing to MainView.  Maybe a better approach is to make subview part of MainWindow instead?  I dind't want to do that, because i will have to re-implement 3 classes and i thought that i was almost done =)  But well, that's developper life!

Comment: Not sure why you would have to reimplement 3 classes to add a subview to the mainWindow but that might be a good thing as it may give you some idea how to structure your code better to handle changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this myself.  Like you, my 'B' view launched my 'C' view and portions of 'C' outside of 'B' were unavailable.

My solution was slightly different because in my case 'C' was totally outside of, but bound to, 'B' (and was opened by 'B').

In my case, I simply attached 'C' to 'A' and made use of @property callbacks to communicate changes in 'C' with 'B' (via 'A').

In your case, another solution would be to simply extend the frame of 'B' to encompass 'C' - you can extend it back once 'C' is no longer visible.  Make the background of 'B' to be clear.